# setting up nic on ubuntu server 18.04 lts

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I have a netronome nic installed on my server.
When I use 50-cloud-init.yaml, this nic's interface doesn't show up.
This nic's interface is : enp4s0np1 and when I use

```
sudo ifconfig enp4s0np1 192.168.1.2/24
```

I can ping to this interface correctly from another server that is connected with this server. 
However, when I type in :

```
enp4s0np1 :
  dhcp4 : true
  addresses:
  - 192.168.1.2/24
```

and I do netplan apply, I can not ping to this interface from another server.

Any idea what's the problem..?

Thanks.

Comment: But why do you also have `dhcp4` enabled?

Comment: @grawity It was just set as true by default. Should I set it to false?